# Create Java 8 Stream from ArrayNode

Tags: jackson, java-8, java-stream, fasterxml

Is it possible to create stream from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode`?
I tried:

```
ArrayNode files = (ArrayNode) json.get("files");
Stream<JsonNode> stream = Stream.of(files);
```

But it will actually give stream of one element, the initial ArrayNode object.
Correct result should be `Stream<JsonNode>`, can I achieve it?

Comment: Will the entire array here be loaded in memory? I believe the answer is "yes". So what is the point to have a stream here?

Comment: @AndreyKarayvansky it's not about performance but about ability to use `Java 8 Stream API` methods to process `ArrayNode` collection in a "functional way" (using methods like `map`, `filter`, `collect`...).

Comment: Lists.newArrayList(arrayNode.elements()).stream() //by Guava

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`ArrayNode` implements `Iterable`. Iterable has a [`spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#spliterator--) method. You can [create a sequential Stream from a Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) using

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) json.get("xyz");
StreamSupport.stream(arrayNode.spliterator(), false)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works but I don't understand why Stream.of(files) didn't while spliterator did.

Comment: Because Stream.of() expects an array as argument, and an ArrayNode is not an array.

Answer (score 20):

An [`ArrayNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html) class provides random access: you can get `size()` and an element by index (using `get(index)`). This is all you need to create a good stream:

```
Stream<JsonNode> nodes = IntStream.range(0, files.size()).mapToObj(files::get);
```

Note that this solution is better than using default spliterator (as suggested by other answerers) as it can split well and reports the size properly. Even if you don't care about parallel processing, some operations like `toArray()` will work more effectively as knowing the size in advance will help to allocate an array of proper size.

Comment: I agree with all you said and this is in many ways better solution. But I would expect to see such solution directly in `ArrayNode` class or as some `Utils` method. Streams should make code easier to read and understand. Using this solution for simple filter-map-collect operation would slightly increase complexity of code. Anyway, very nice thinking, you got my +1.

Comment: @klerik, It's not so easy to provide stream API methods while maintaining pre-Java-8 compatibility.

Comment: I like this as it means I don't have to cast my `JsonNode` to an `ArrayNode` either.

Answer (score 5):

ArrayNode#elements returns an Iterator over it's elements you can use that to create a Stream (by leveraging StreamSupport). StreamSupport requires a Spliterator and to create a Spliterator from an Iterator you can use the Spliterators class.

```
  ArrayNode files = (ArrayNode) json.get("files");
  Stream<JsonNode>  elementStream = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators
                  .spliteratorUnknownSize(files.elements(),
                        Spliterator.ORDERED),false);
```

[cyclops-streams](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams) has a [StreamUtils](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-streams/6.0.2/com/aol/cyclops/streams/StreamUtils.html)  class has a static method that makes this a bit cleaner (I am the author).

```
 ArrayNode files = (ArrayNode) json.get("files");
 Stream<JsonNode>  elementStream = StreamUtils.stream(files.elements());
```

Taking into account @JB Nizet's answer that ArrayNode is an iterable with StreamUtils you can pass in the ArrayNode and get the Stream back directly.

```
Stream<JsonNode>  elementStream = StreamUtils.stream((ArrayNode) json.get("files"));
```